# Python Date-Format

Tags: python, date, format

I want to change input datetime format to output datetime format:
input datetime format = 05 Apr 2021 06:46:16 GMT

Then i did:

input = input.replace(newdate[:5],"")
#05 Apr 2021 06:46:16 GMT

output datetime format 05/04/2021 06:46:16

Comment: Have you looked at the `datetime` module at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
input_format = '05 Apr 2021 06:46:16 GMT'
input_list = input_format.split() #split the string and store in list
modified_input = " ".join(input_list[0:-1]) #removing the last element which is GMT and then joining all the strings in the list
output_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(modified_input, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
print(output_format.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```